# iOS auto_resizing code for each layouts

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, autolayout, swift4

Hi I am working on creating a view with code below.
I would like to make this code to auto layout to each iPhone sizes. 
Which code should I add more?

There exist four emoticons in this code in the view, so I want to make each of them resizing itself regardless of iPhone layout such as iPhone 8, SE, 8+ and so on.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
let firstView:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "angry").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
let secondView:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "crying").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     return imageView
}()

let thirdView:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heartEmpty").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

let fourthView:UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "joy").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()


func setupViews() {

    view.addSubview(firstView)

   // setup first view
    firstView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    firstView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(secondView)

// setup second view
    secondView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    secondView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
   secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
view.addSubview(thirdView)

   thirdView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
   thirdView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
   thirdView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
   thirdView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
   view.addSubview(fourthView)

   fourthView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
  fourthView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
   fourthView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
   fourthView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to insert them all in a horizontal `UIStackView` with fill-Equally, by this   items will resize according to the current size of the stackview